# Number of pins of elements

Tags: encoder, footprint, orcad

I've created a footprint for the rotary encoder, which symbol is shown below

[image]

A footprint for this element has been done by myself.

[image]

I've been getting a warning which goes like this:

"WARNING(ORCAP-2435): Number of pins in footprint 'PEC11L-4XXXF-SXXXX' and instance 'EN1' does not match."

How can I get rid of that error?

Answer (score 1):

Add pins to symbol to connect shield. You should connect them to GND.